# Angular orderBy is not working in safari, how can i resolve this?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular 2 project, here I have a code to sort order, it is working fine in chrome and firefox but , it is working for the first time in safari on load, later it will not sort. Can I get any solution for this issue?

Comment: You should enable polyfills. Checkout https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Hi, please add your code to the question

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time, I found the issue, I have used the Date timestamp, which was returning undefined. so I used the following code, 
new Date(a.timestamp.replace(/ /g,"T"));